# DllImport возвратить результат функции в виде структуры

Tags: c#, delphi

Всем здравствуйте. Помогите справиться с такой проблемой. Переписываю функции проигрывания bik видео на C#.

```
public enum BinkOpenEnum {
    BINK_OPEN_STREAM = 0x800000
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TBink {
    public uint Width;
    public uint Height;
    public uint Frames;
    public uint CurrentFrame;
    public uint LastFrame;
    public uint FrameRate;
    public uint FrameRate2;
    public uint ErrorCode;
    public uint Flags;
}
[DllImport("binkw32.dll")]
public static extern TBink BinkOpen(string filename, BinkOpenEnum flags);

void Start () {
    public TBink bink2 = new TBink();
    bink2 = BinkOpen("D:\\bikVideo.bik", BinkOpenEnum.BINK_OPEN_STREAM);
}
```

Потом вывожу значения bink2.Width, bink2.Height и т.д. и получаю совсем не те числа, вообще огромные числа и то они иногда меняются при каждом запуске программы.
Вот так код выглядит на Delphi:

```
type
    HBink = ^Tbink;

    Tbink = packed record
        Width, Height, Frames: Longword;
        CurrentFrame: Longword;
        LastFrame: Longword;
        FrameRate: Longword;
        FrameRate2: Longword;
        ErrorCode: Longword;
        Flags: Longword;
    end;

var
    Fmovie: HBink;
    FMODHandle: THandle;
    BinkOpen: function(Filename: PChar; Flags: Longword): HBink; stdcall;
begin
    FMODHandle := LoadLibrary('binkw32.dll');
    @BinkOpen := GetAddress(FMODHandle, '_BinkOpen@8');
    Fmovie := BinkOpen('D:\bikVideo.bik', BINK_OPEN_STREAM);
end;
```

Здесь функция возвращает указатель на структуру, также это наблюдается на C++. Помогите такое реализовать на C#, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, насколько я понимаю, второй аргумент функции `BinkOpen` должен иметь тип `uint`.
Во-вторых, попробуйте задекларировать функцию, чтобы она возвращала указатель:

```
private static extern IntPtr BinkOpen(string filename, BinkOpenEnum flags);
```

После этого можно скопировать структуру из неуправляемой области памяти, адресуемой указателем, в управляемый контекст при помощи метода [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx).

В результате должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
public enum BinkOpenEnum : uint
{
    BINK_OPEN_STREAM = 0x800000
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Bink
{
    public uint Width;
    public uint Height;
    public uint Frames;
    public uint CurrentFrame;
    public uint LastFrame;
    public uint FrameRate;
    public uint FrameRate2;
    public uint ErrorCode;
    public uint Flags;
}
[DllImport("binkw32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr BinkOpen(string filename, BinkOpenEnum flags);

public static Bink BinkOpen(string filename)
{
    IntPtr hBink = BinkOpen(filename, BinkOpenEnum.BINK_OPEN_STREAM);
    return (Bink)Marshal.PtrToStructure(hBink, typeof(Bink));
}
```